# Improving performance of query using Like operator in Where clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with 25 million records.

An update statement has to be fired to replace some characters from account numbers. Query Syntax,

```
Update T1
set col1=  REPLACE(col1’@123;','''')
,col2=  REPLACE(col2,'@123;','''')
where col1 like '%@123;%'
or col2 like '%@123;%'
;
```

The statement takes around 2 hours to execute. What would be the best approach to reduce execution time?

Note: table has non-clustered index on col1

Comment: REPLACE(col1’@123;','''') isnt there a typo, an extra missing , in front and then '@123'

Comment: Can you post code that would actually run? I also don't think this is a useful level of info. What type, length, etc. are these columns?

Comment: also yre you sure you wana replace @123; with ' ' , sounds a bit odd to have ' ' in your text

Comment: If the query works but is just very slow, and needs to be done only once, than just run it at night and be done with it

Comment: If it's run only once and it does job perfectly, 2h is not that much of a time. Test on smaller data set 1st to avoid unwanted results.